# Weird border artefacts when taking screenshots with `import`

Tags: linux, imagemagick, screenshot, awesome-wm

I take screenshots with Imagemagick's `import` command such as `import /tmp/screen.png`.

When I drag an area on screen, it shows an outline of the area I'm about to capture, but it's a little finnicky -- it's not always visible, and sometimes lags behind the pointer.

Whether or not I see an outline when choosing an area, the output image is sometimes totally fine, sometimes has an outline (which may or may not be complete), and sometimes it has an outline which goes around some subset of the image.

Here are some example screenshots I took just now. In all cases, the vertical blue line is expected.

1. This one has an outline around a subset of the total area:
   [image]
2. This one has an outline around the very edges, but a black dot in the top left:
   [image]
3. This one is totally fine:
   [image]

Anybody know what's wrong or how I can fix it? My window manager is [AwesomeWM](https://awesomewm.org/), if that makes a difference.

Comment: This is probably related to the compositing manager used. In my case, I killed `compton` and I didn't have those artifacts anymore. Probably need some tinkering with the compositing manager's configuration.